# Casting value-type constants

Tags: c#, casting, constants

This is more of an academic question than one where I'm really worried about the performance. I'm just really curious is all. I've also learned in my, admittedly limited, programming experience that the compiler is only smart about half the time.

I have a static class where a constant `int` is defined and I need to divide that constant by another integer. Now, I need a float value returned from that division, so I can't just leave them both as integers.

```
const int CONSTANTINTEGER = 69;
int integer = 0;
float floatValue = 0f;

for(integer = 0; integer < CONSTANTINTEGER; integer++) {
    float floatValue = integer / (float)CONSTANTINTEGER;
    //use floatValue for algorithm.....
}
```

Now, my question: Is the compiler smart enough to create a constant float in place of the `(float)CONSTANTINTEGER` or does it cast the integer to a float every single loop?

Comment: seems like it would cast each iteration, just like declaring a variable within a loop seems like it would be recreated and the fall out of scope each iteration.. but, honestly, I am not sure

Comment: You can compile it, then look at the compiled assembly in ILSpy.  If you look at the IL, you'll see where its doing the cast.

Comment: @Amy: Or rather, where it's *not* doing the cast, because it *is* a constant. It needs to cast `integer` to `float` each time, but not `CONSTANTINTEGER`. If you disagree, feel free to add an answer with more details and we can look more closely.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess he _could_ make the `for` loop variable have type `float`. Then the dividend would not have to be cast from `int` each time. However, generally using a `float` or `double` for incrementing in a loop can be dangerous if you come into a "domain" where the delta step is not exactly representable in the `float`. But whole numbers `0f` to `68f` are represented exactly, of course.

Comment: @Jeppe: Yes, I certainly wasn't advocating that. Just trying to clarify exactly what Amy meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language specification helps us out here. Section 7.19 of the C# 5 spec states:

> A constant expression must be the null literal or a value with one of  the following types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, object, string, or any enumeration type. Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> - ...
> - Cast expressions, provided the target type is one of the types listed above.
>
> ...
>
> Whenever an expression fulfills the requirements listed above, the expression is evaluated at compile-time. This is true even if the expression is a sub-expression of a larger expression that contains non-constant constructs.

You can also validate this by looking at the IL, which in this case has:

```
IL_000a:  ldc.r4     69.
```

when it's loading the divisor for the division operation.